# Mustache (php) and objects?

Tags: php, mustache

Given the following example, can anyone recommend a best practice for accessing $string or HelloWorld::getString() from a template without extending the Mustache class?

```
<?php    
Class HelloWorld{
    protected $string;
    function __construct(){
        $this->string = 'Hello World';
    }
    function setString($str) { $this->string = $str; }
    function getString() { return $this->string; }
}

# here goes nothing
$h = new HelloWorld();
$m = new Mustache();
echo $m->render('{{string}}', $h);
?>
```

As you would imagine, if I make $string public, it works as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

This is embarrassing. The solution is simply:

```
{{getString}}
```

Comment: Lol. I didn't laugh for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at PHP's [magic](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) `__get` and `__set` methods.

Try it like this:

```
Class HelloWorld{
    protected $string;
    function __construct(){
        $this->string = 'Hello World';
    }
    function __set($var, $value) { 
        switch($var){
            case 'string': $this->string = $value; break;
            default: // do nothing //
        }
    }
    function __get($var) { 
        switch($var){
            case 'string': return $this->string;
            default: // do nothing //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was really helpful in answering the "what am I missing" question. Thank you. Problem is that it doesn't seem to be the solution while working with Mustache.